# LTspice showing wrong voltage

Tags: led, resistors, dc, ltspice

I am trying to get this circuit to work correctly. I am following a book, and according to Ohm's law this resistor should be 350 Ω to get 2 V at the LED. I am only seeing around 800 mV.

To get around 2 V at the LED in LTspice I need a 10 pΩ resistor which doesn't make sense. What am I doing wrong? Or is the example in the book incorrect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are using the default diode model. Use a real diode.

Comment: Also, is that resistor really supposed to be 10p? That's a really really small value.

Comment: @Hearth means that you should use a real LED model.  LEDs tend to have a much greater forward voltage than typical signal diodes.  I think however, that there's another question you should be asking...

Comment: No according to the book I am following its supposed to be 350 ohms. But if I set it to 350 ohms the voltage at the LED is 800mv.

Comment: To state it more clearly, your problem is that the default diode model in LTspice has a forward voltage of around 700 to 800 mV (and, apparently, unphysically low series resistance). This represents a silicon PN junction diode, *not* an LED. Using a model of an actual LED (specifically a red, yellow, or green one) will give you around 1.7 V forward voltage and substantial enough series resistance to drive that up to 2 V with only a little extra current.

Comment: @Hearth thanks for clarifying the problem. Does LTSpice include this model or is it an external one that I need to add?

Comment: If you look through the diode models (right click the diode and click "pick new diode"), you might find one; I'm not sure. Otherwise, find a model from an LED manufacturer. It's pretty rare that you need to simulate little indicator LEDs though, so you might have a hard time finding one.

Comment: I've always found that the built-in `QTLP690C` LED model works well as a drop-in for a generic green or red LED.

Comment: Here's a red LED model that will do what you want: .model APT-2012EC d(IS=2.01E-17 N=2.139 RS=4.4 m=0.431 Vj=2.32 Cjo=35pF IBV=10u BV=5 EG=2.26 XTI=3 Iave=20mA Vpk=5 mfg=Kingbright type=LED)  You can add this line to standard.dio if APT-2012EC is not there already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few quick points:

- Do use the LTspice help. If you access it using the menu, there is an option for searching and you can use "diode" or just "d" in the search, then look down for something that says "diode" on it and click on that. This will get you to a page with some useful, technical information about diode models. It may still be a bit unfamiliar, but I want to make sure that you think about accessing the help, anyway. Sometimes, regardless of how prepared you are, you can find something helpful there.
- LEDs are diodes. But they operate at distinctly higher voltage differences than do diodes used for full wave rectifiers, for example. So you should be warned that any time someone says "diode" it's almost a knee-reaction to ask, "What kind of diode?" before considering using it in LTspice.

  There are many kinds of diodes, but the usual suspects are rectifier (power) diodes, signal (not power) diodes, LEDs (higher voltage differences than usual), Schottky diodes (somewhat lower voltage differences than usual, and a little "leaky"), and Zener diodes (usually used with a reverse-voltage applied to them to gain access to their voltage-knee behavior.)

  Just be aware that not all diodes are the same and that you need to have some basic idea about which kind you are working with and how to access the behavior you'd like to see over the range of operation you expect.

This brings us back to the LTspice documentation. If you read it, you will see that they discuss two essentially different types of diode models.

This first one is described by the first table in the help on diodes. There are basically just two things you care about with this one: \$V_{_\text{FWD}}\$ and \$R_{_\text{ON}}\$. \$V_{_\text{FWD}}\$ sets the voltage for the diode when there is no current at all. And \$R_{_\text{ON}}\$ is multiplied by the LED current to get an additional voltage drop to add to the total voltage drop, which by definition varies with the current. \$R_{_\text{ON}}\$ gives a bit of variation of the diode behavior that depends on the current through it.

This first model is only *good* for a short range of planned currents. But this simpler model is also a pretty good model to pick for LEDs. That's because most LEDs are only supposed to be operated over just such a small range of currents. For example, low power, high efficiency LEDs will be operated within a factor of 3 or so of \$2\:\text{mA}\$. Low power, standard LEDs will be operated within a factor of 3 or so of \$20\:\text{mA}\$. And high power LEDs will be operated usually within a factor of 3 of whatever current they are spec'd for.

So the range of operating current for LEDs are generally limited and that makes this simpler model a good fit for them.

Plus, it avoids the trickery needed to get a good fit using the more complex model of the second one discussed on the LTspice help page. This other complex model is called the Shockley diode model. Because the Shockley model is designed to work accurately over a very much wider range of currents that span over many orders of magnitude change, it is necessarily more complex because over such a wide dynamic range there are more effects that come into play.

Luckily, you don't need this more complex Shockley model.

So let's return to the simple model:

$$V_{_\text{D}}=V_{_\text{FWD}}+R_{_\text{ON}}\cdot I_{_\text{D}}$$

Just doing a quick check, I see that \$I_{_\text{D}}=\frac{9\:\text{V}-2\:\text{V}}{350\:\Omega}=20\:\text{mA}\$. So this tells me this is about a standard low power LED.

We could cheat a bit and just set \$R_{_\text{ON}}=0\:\Omega\$ (or something really small.)

But because I want to teach you to use it a little better, let's assume something a little more meaningful, like \$R_{_\text{ON}}=20\:\Omega\$.

At \$I_{_\text{D}}=20\:\text{mA}\$, the voltage drop across \$R_{_\text{ON}}\$ will be \$20\:\Omega\cdot 20\:\text{mA}=400\:\text{mV}\$. So to get a total voltage drop of \$2\:\text{V}\$, we have to subtract that and find \$V_{_\text{FWD}}=2\:\text{v}-400\:\text{mV}=1.6\:\text{V}\$.

So that's the model.

Just hit 'S' in LTspice to get the dialog box and type in as shown:

[image]

Then place that line on the schematic somewhere.

Here's what I did:

[image]

*Note that I edited the "D" and changed it to "MYLED" on the diode, itself!*

And that's all you need to do.

Let's run it:

[image]

Note that the diode current is exactly \$20\:\text{mA}\$!! And note that the voltage drop across it is also exactly \$2\:\text{V}\$.

That's how you can get LTspice to readily handle simple LED cases.

I went to a little extra trouble to create a non-zero value for \$R_{_\text{ON}}\$. You don't have to do that. But LTspice doesn't exactly like \$R_{_\text{ON}}=0\$ and instead applies some numerical tricks that will actually generate numerical oddities when you try and cheat like that. It's better to just pick a reasonable value and go with it. Besides, it also gives your LED something closer to a more realistic behavior when you do that, too.

Comment: +1 for opting to use the PWL diode model, especially for things like textbook problems and such where they use a PWL model in hand calculations.

Answer (score 5):

There are some LED models already in LTspice, you can try some of them. They will have different forward voltages so each one will give you a different result.

When I want to use an LED with a particular voltage drop I add a model using a spice directive on my schematic containing something like:

```
.model MYLED D(Is=1e-19 N=2.0 Rs=2.5 Eg=2.5)
```

Then I Ctrl + right click on the LED symbol on the schematic and change *Value* to the name of the model, in this case MYLED. The value in the model that says *N=2.0* is what you change to set the voltage to roughly what you want (it will vary with current so it's not going to be exact).

You should get something like this:
[image]

You can also use an existing model and alias it with AKO: to use a more complete model and change specific attributes. You would do the same as above but use a .MODEL statement like this:

```
.MODEL MYLED AKO:QTLP690C N=2.3
```

This would give you a model named MYLED that has all the attributes of the QTLP690C that is included in LTspice, but N is changed from 1.5 to 2.3 or whatever you want to set it at. AKO: (A Kind Of) is a useful tool in LTspice, you can use it to clone models and change things like the beta of transistors and \$V_Z\$ voltage of Zener diodes.

Comment: I'm not sure N is the best value to change for this, though it does sort of work. The actual forward voltage is a complicated combination of a bunch of factors, and N is rarely outside the range (1, 2), even for diodes with forward voltages much less than 1 or much greater than 2.

Comment: @heath It seems to work well enough for non-critical purposes, such as making different color LEDs with different forward voltages. You have to tweak the number a bit to get the voltage you want but I've found it generally useful.